# Add property to list of a class

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, properties

I have a List of a OrdersInfo
I inherit OrdersInfo into YearlyResourceReport and add 12 properties - months (public string Jan {get;set;}) etc

Now i create a list of the new class (So [OldProperties] + [12Month])

How can i merge the two lists together?

```
class YearlyResourceReport : OrdersInfo
{
    public string Jan { get; set; }
    public string Feb { get; set; }
    public string Mar { get; set; }
    public string Apr { get; set; }
    public string Jun { get; set; }
    public string Jul { get; set; }
    public string Aug { get; set; }
    public string Sep { get; set; }
    public string Oct { get; set; }
    public string Nov { get; set; }
    public string Dec { get; set; }

}
```

Addition:

```
List<OrdersInfo> ordersList = 
WorkOrderEntity.GetYearlyOrders(year, loggedInUser, customerIds, sortBy).ToList();

List<YearlyResourceReport> newList;
```

I wish to either add properties to first list(without having to create a second list at all)
Or just as a last measure merge both lists.

Comment: what is your question relation to the title?

Comment: Merge in what way? Question is unclear. What is your desired result?

Comment: what do you mean exactly by adding a property to list of a class do you have such properties in OrdersInfo and you see duplicated properties

Comment: you want to have order info with Jan,feb,... properties so declare them in Order info class and when you inherit YearlyResourceReport you got those properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work as an example to get you going down the right path:

```
class A
{
    public string PropertyA { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return this.PropertyA; }
}

class B : A
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", this.PropertyA, this.PropertyB); }
}

var aList = new List<A>();
var bList = new List<B>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    aList.Add(new A() { PropertyA = string.Format("A - {0}", i) });
    bList.Add(new B() { PropertyA = string.Format("B::A - {0}", i), PropertyB = string.Format("B::B - {0}", i) });
}

// now list the current state of the two lists
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(aList[i]);
    Console.WriteLine(bList[i]);
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine();

// now merge the lists and print that result
var newList = bList.Concat(aList.Select(a => new B() { PropertyA = a.PropertyA, PropertyB = "Created by system." }));
foreach (var item in newList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

In the above example I have a class `A` and `B` and `B` inherits from `A` and adds a property. I then build a listing of both and write them out to the `Console`. After doing that we then merge the two lists, creating `B`'s out of the `A`'s because a singular generic list must have the same type. You could conceivably use something like an `ArrayList` instead of a generic list and house two different types - but I don't think that's what you're looking for.

Once merging the types we write out the results of that merge to the `Console` as well and you see the two lists merged.

If your requirements are a little different, this will get you more than 90% of the way, because honestly your question didn't contain very much information so you left us to kind of **assume** some things.

**NOTE:** I used `scriptcs` to compile, run, and prove this example so that's why it's not as structured.

Answer (score 1):

If i do understand your question correctly you would like to do it something like this.

```
// Your class definitions
public class YearlyResourceReport
{
    public YearlyResourceReport()
    {
        this.MonthlyResourceReports = new List<MonthlyOrderInfo>();
    }

    public List<MonthlyOrderInfo> MonthlyResourceReports { get; set; }
}

public class MonthlyOrderInfo
{
    public string Month { get; set; }
    public int MonthNumber { get; set; }
    public OrdersInfo OrdersInfo { get; set; }
}

public class OrdersInfo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int TotalOrders { get; set; }
    public double TotalRevenue { get; set; }
}
```

You could create the containing YearlyResourceReport class as follows:

```
 public YearlyResourceReport GetYearlyOrders()
 {
    YearlyResourceReport yrr = new YearlyResourceReport();
    for(int i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
    {
        yrr.MonthlyResourceReports.Add(new MonthlyOrderInfo {
        moi.MonthNumber = i,
        moi.OrdersInfo = WorkOrderEntity.GetMonthlyOrders(year, i, loggedInUser, customerIds, sortBy).ToList()
        });
    }
    return result;
 }
```